# When I try to compile Caffe, I get an error: “error: expected function body after function declarator”

Tags: macos, caffe

When I try to compile [Caffe](https://caffe.berkeleyvision.org) on macOS, I get this error. What can I do to fix this?

```
/usr/local/include/leveldb/status.h:115:48: error: expected function body after function declarator
inline Status& Status::operator=(Status&& rhs) noexcept {
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question but I got past the issue by finding an appropriate definition of COMMON_FLAGS in the Makefile and added a flag for c++11.

Was

```
    COMMON_FLAGS += -DCPU_ONLY
```

and I made it

```
    COMMON_FLAGS += -DCPU_ONLY -std=c++11
```

There are multiple places in the Makefile where COMMON_FLAGS is modified. You need to make the change in the right place. That will depend on other flags you set in the Makefile.config file.